# How to add url query to a path in Vue.js router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

This is how the route is used in template Component.vue:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'club' }">
  <lazy-image
    src="club.jpg"
    class="club_class"
    alt="Club alt"
  />
</router-link>
```

And this is how it's defined in router.js:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/s/site',
        name: 'club',
        component: () => import('./_pages/Club'),
    },
];
export default routes;
```

I need to add a just a static parameter to the link like this:

```
'?foo=bar'
```

I tried to hardcode that in Component.vue but it didn't work. Shoud I define it in router.js as param or somewhere else?

Comment: `:to="{ name: 'club', query:{ foo: 'bar' } }"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'club', query: {param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2'}}">go</router-link>
```